# Hot to find records that not exists on the other table in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I am a newbie in both SQL and BigQuery.
I have a problem which to find records that do not exist on the other table.

Suppose I have table A which contains complete data and it has its own timestamp when the records were inserted, and Table B which does insert snapshot data of that day of table A.

My 1st query with "LEFT OUTER JOIN" per below:

```
select count(1) 
from table_a a
left outer join table_b b on (a.id =b.id)
where b.id is null
```

using above SQL which returned 0 results

and SQL below with "NOT EXIST":

```
select count(1)
from table_a a
where not exists (
        select 1
        from table_b b
        where a.id = b.id
    )
```

which return many records.

Now I am confused about which SQL that telling me the truth because I believe that Table B had missed one or two days of sync from Table A. How can I tell there are missing records is because I use several sample IDs on Table A that did not exist on Table B.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the statement `IN`. This statement returns the rows from Table A, which is not found in Table B.

I will explain how it works.

Table A has all the data

[image]

Table B has missing rows from Table A

[image]

In this case, you need to know what rows are missing in table B. You will use the “in” statement. First, you will select all
Rows from Table A and then you will compare the information with table B and will return the rows that are missing in table B.

You can see this example

```
select text
from `Table A`
where text not in (select text from `TableB`)
```

This was the result. The rows from table A, which are missing from table B.

[image]

You can see more [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/expression_subqueries) about these expression subqueries.

Comment: @lagunaloire Did my answer help you?